# How to hang a program in C++ and then "unhang" it

Tags: c++

What's the best way to hang a C++ program for a certain amount of time?

Given the fact that the program is unresponsive during this time, is it possible to control when the program returns to normal?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/sleep_for

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "responsiveness" of program sounds to me as something OS specific, not C++ ... for example in MS windows the program is supposed to process window events, if it stops reading the event queue, the windows will after some time claim it as being "not responding"... while the app can still do many things in its code, i.e. do some calculations or modify files or communicate over network, i.e. far from "unresponsive". But to play it nicely with the OS, most of the apps regularly peek into the queue to let windows know that they are "alive" and responding to the OS events (which does include also keydown/up events, window resize/move, requests for redraw of window content, etc = many things you really want to do regularly in GUI app any way).

So the question is if you want to make your app "unresponsive" in the OS way (and continue to do things in the background) = then just stop processing OS specific calls/events and "play dead" while computing your own stuff as you wish, or you want just to pause it's normal operation and do "nothing", until resumed.

(edit: the modern operating systems are using preemptive multitasking, giving some CPU time to every running process, switching between them every few micro/milli-seconds to create illusion of processes running at the "same time", so if you don't use the `sleep`-like solution, just running some loop waiting for external signal like unlocking of file or network packet, you will be burning lot of CPU time for nothing, which could have been used by other apps)

If you want to pause the app, the best way to spend the idle time is to use `sleep` function, that gives the CPU time back to OS, using minimal amount of system resources. You can still process OS events in a loop interleaved with like 1-3s sleeps, so the OS will think about your app as "responding" and you can even have UI to pause/resume, but your app will use negligible CPU time.

How do you signal the pause/resume events to the app depends what you want to use to control it. You can use platform specific IPC (Inter-Process Communication), or network packets, UI buttons, filesystem events (locking/unlocking particular shared file to provide inter-process synchronization or data passing) or the OS events (like on android you can listen for OS events like locking/unlocking the display by user, etc).

None of this is (except `sleep` function) standardized in C++ to the point that I could give more detailed answer, and as you didn't specify anything about your compiler and target OS, I wrote this general chit-chat answer.

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you! I'm using Unreal Engine and because `sleep` is platform-specific, I did a little digging and it looks like UE itself has a platform-independent function called `FPlatformProcess::Sleep`. Your answer helped me dig deeper and, lo and behold, I found something!

Comment: The Unreal Engine is cross-platform, so it has it's own main control loop dealing with OS specific event handling and stuff, you should always check first Unreal API to make your app depend only on Unreal engine, which will make it possibly-cross-platform "for free" (in reality usually the other platforms will demonstrate some bugs/incompatibilities you were not aware of, so if you want your work to be cross-platform, you should set up your workflow to build all target platforms all the time, and discover any issues as early as possible).

Comment: @AlexWeyland I actually never read Unreal API, but I'm pretty sure it has not only it's own `Sleep`, but it has also network API, and file API functions, both of them can be used to communicate between two Unreal apps (think about multiplayer client-server, where the server is idling while no client is connected)... with the UE being the long time behemoth and de facto leader, it surely has all of this covered, probably in multiple variations, and probably also with some examples of idiomatic ways how to achieve common goals.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the standard C++ threading library. std::this_thread::sleep_for() will allow you to sleep for a defined amount of time. This will allow you to achieve your goal on any platform with the same code.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "tick\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for( 500ms );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can run the code here : https://onlinegdb.com/HkqZkpmUB

The chrono library allows you to use some predefined "user defined literals" these https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal. To use a user defined literal you must be at namespace scope. Thats what this line does, it allows me to use 500ms:

```
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
```

The sleep_for function causes the thread which called it to sleep for the defined amount of time. If that thread is the GUI or console thread then it will be unresponsive.